# Speeding up OHLC Calculations of csv data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, csv, data-science

I have a csv file that contains OHLC data for stocks. All I need to do is take 1st value of 'Open' and assign it to the 1st value of new column 'Base' and then take its 2% increase,2% decrease and
assign that values in 2 new columns.[Here is the sample data of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB3Ch.jpg)
The expected output is, [This is the sample expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr96F.jpg)

I tried using for and if loops for the same, here is the code which I tried, it is working fine but takes lot of time for complete csv file which contains more than 500K entries.[Code snippet for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RduN.jpg)

Any sort of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reformat your question so that to fit all of the [minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the problem, and paste examples of your data. Linking to them is considered not acceptable (please read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: Hello, I am not yet allowed to embed images of the file, so I attached the links.

Comment: How about copying the *text* into the question?